# How to split every row in dataframe into two with some features?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
A  C1 C2
a1 c1 c3
a2 c2 c4
```

And columns C1 and C2 has the same type.

And I want get this:

```
A  C
a1 c1
a1 c3
a2 c2
a2 c4
```

How I can do this?

**UPD:**
In answers I get this info:

```
df_final = df.set_index('A').stack().droplevel(1).rename('C').reset_index()

Out[604]:
    A   C
0  a1  c1
1  a1  c3
2  a2  c2
3  a2  c4
```

But what I should if I want split in this way?

```
A  B  C1 C2 C3 C4
a1 b1 c1 c2 c3 c4
a2 b2 c5 c6 c7 c8
```

and get this:

```
A  B  C1 C2
a1 b1 c1 c2
a1 b1 c3 c4
a2 b2 c5 c6
a2 b2 c7 c8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2**: If you have even number of columns `Cx`, you may use numpy to make it simple

```
import numpy as np

cols = ['C1','C2','C3','C4']
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(cols) / 2), ['A','B']].reset_index(drop=True)
df_final = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(df[cols].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2), columns=['C1','C2']))

Out[698]:
    A   B  C1  C2
0  a1  b1  c1  c2
1  a1  b1  c3  c4
2  a2  b2  c5  c6
3  a2  b2  c7  c8
```

---

**Edit for updated sample**:

On multiple columns `Cx` splitting by 2, you need `wide_to_long`. However, beforing doing it, you need pre-processing columns names to appropriate format to use with `wide_to_long`

```
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])
stub_cols = (np.arange(df1.columns.size) % 2).astype(str)
suff_cols =  (np.arange(df1.columns.size) // 2).astype(str)
d = dict(zip(stub_cols, ['C1', 'C2']))
df1.columns = pd.Series(stub_cols) + '_' + suff_cols

df_final = pd.wide_to_long(df1.reset_index(), 
                           i=['A','B'], 
                           j='num', 
                           stubnames=['0','1'], 
                           sep='_').droplevel(-1).rename(d, axis=1).reset_index()

Out[680]:
    A   B  C1  C2
0  a1  b1  c1  c2
1  a1  b1  c3  c4
2  a2  b2  c5  c6
3  a2  b2  c7  c8
```

---

Give this a try

```
df_final = df.set_index('A').stack().droplevel(1).rename('C').reset_index()

Out[604]:
    A   C
0  a1  c1
1  a1  c3
2  a2  c2
3  a2  c4
```

Comment: Cool! But what I should do if I want to save in every row two or more columns and split also two or more?

Comment: Edit my question.

Comment: So sorry! I am edit the last time about four C columns. Can you check?

Comment: @dasfex: check my latest edited

Comment: @dasfex: I added another solution using `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

```
print( 
    pd.concat([df.A, df[['C1', 'C2']].apply(list, axis=1)], axis=1).explode(0).rename(columns={0:'C'}) 
)
```

Prints:

```
    A   C
0  a1  c1
0  a1  c3
1  a2  c2
1  a2  c4
```